# SilverStripe 3.1 routing and Link function

Tags: hyperlink, routes, silverstripe

I'm updating a SilverStripe website from 2.4 to 3.1.

I have many Links functions used in controllers and views.

The problem is that when I set routes.yml like this

```
Director:
  rules:
    'gottesdienste//$Action/$ID/$OtherID' : LiturgiesPage_Controller
    'veranstaltungen//$Action/$ID/$OtherID' : ArrangementsPage_Controller
```

Links in my site change from

```
gottesdienste/archive/2012
```

to

```
LiturgiesPage_Controller/archive/2012
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: And $Title and $Content in template dont'n work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [`Link()`](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller#linking-to-a-controller) method that uses the base string you want.

```
public function Link($action = null) {
    return self::join_links('gottesdienste', $action);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works like this: return self::join_links('veranstaltungen/', $action); But link to holder in template $URLSegment still returns LiturgiesPage_Controller

Comment: You shouldn't be using $URLSegment. Just use $Link.